# Unifi video email alerts show 'invalid address' error

Tags: gmail, ip-camera

I'm getting following error when trying to configure email alerts in Unifi Video:

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 553 5.1.3 The recipient address <null> is not a valid 
RFC-5321 address. a187sm3126010wmh.33 - gsmtp
```

I have an email address set, smtp.gmail.com with port 465, SSL, and authentication with a valid user/pass.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your own email address in your user profile. Go to the top right icon, click 'my account' and enter your email address.
Now try again, the email should go through just fine.